# "no such file or directory" while trying to install gcloud commandline tool

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

OK so I am trying to download gcloud compute but I am unable to for some reason. I followed the step by step guide from this [page](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs) but when I type *./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init* the terminal returns *zsh: no such file or directory: ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud*

Should I move google-cloud-sdk out of download into some other places? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

If it is any help, I am currently using Mac OS catalina 10.15.4. [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have downloaded the SDK into a different directory than you are currently in with your terminal.

Try moving the downloaded *google-cloud-sdk* folder into your home (or *cd* into your Downloads folder with the terminal), and then running the command. You can also use `ls` to make sure you are in the correct directory and can see the *google-cloud-sdk* folder.

Comment: this is correct, I made the mistake of trying to run `$ ./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init` from inside the *google-cloud-sdk* folder itself when I should have ran it from the the directory the folder is located in meaning *users/myusername/Downloads* or where ever your *google-cloud-sdk* folder is located